# solution for compare two delimited column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

### i/p

table A

```
emp_id emp_name
1         x
2         y
```

table B

```
auto_id  emp_id    company_name
1         1,2            xxxxx
2         2,3,4,5        yyyyy
```

### o/p

```
auto_id  emp_name  company_name
1         x,y         xxxxx
2         x,y,z,t     yyyyy
```

how to compare these columns?...

Comment: Never store data as comma-separated items! It will only give you lots of trouble!!!

Comment: table b emp_id is varchar so it is saved only

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
select auto_id, emp_name, company_name
from tableA inner join tableB on ',' + tableB.emp_id + ',' like '%,' + cast(tableA.emp_id as nvarchar(50)) + ',%'
```

Comment: which is return empty itself                           i am trying with this query but not return exactly   select t3.*, 
  STUFF(
         (SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.Employee_Name
          FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE as t1
          inner join TBL_Site_Update_POP t2
          on t1.Employee_ID = t2.Employee_ID
    where t2.Employee_ID = t3.Employee_ID
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') Emp_name
from TBL_Site_Update_POP as t3 where t3.Site_Update_Id = 2 and t3.Type='SF';

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86f3f/1

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(XML,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(emp_id,',','</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ') AS emp_idXML
          ,company_name
          ,auto_id 
    FROM tbl2
)

,CTE2
AS
(
   SELECT  T.c.value('.','varchar(max)') AS emp_id
            ,auto_id
            ,company_name
   FROM 
       CTE1 CROSS APPLY
            emp_idXML.nodes('/root/s') AS T(c)
)

SELECT auto_id, STUFF((SELECT ','+isnull(emp_name,'') 
                        FROM tbl1 t inner join cte2 c ON c.emp_id = t.emp_id and c.auto_id = ext.auto_id 
                        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM tbl2 ext
```